# Using mobx store in react-navigation createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobx, mobx-react

I would like to use Mobx store variable in createStackNavigator in react-navigation. Specifically, I would like to change the initial route dynamically (so that user can change the initial screen) using the store. would this be possible? Something in the line of...

```
const stack = createStackNavigator({
Home:{
   ...
},
{
  initialRouteName: this.props.store.initialScreen
{
})
```

Because this is not a class, I cannot integrate mobx store. Any ideas to change the initialRoute dynamically is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have class-based StackNavigator this way:

```
class YourStack extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { initialScreen } = this.props.store;

    const RouteConfigs = {
      //
    };

    const NavigatorConfigs = {
      initialRouteName: initialScreen,
    };

    const Stack = createStackNavigator(RouteConfigs, NavigatorConfigs);
    return <Stack />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. is it okay to have class-based stack navigator(performance issue etc.)? since I've never seen one before

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely fine to do so ... `createStackNavigator ` returns a normal React Component and that's we're done here ... but I'd say to convert it a **functional component** if you're not in need for any component's lifecycle methods

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but I always get error, is it really possible to use class base stack navigators? Any documentation?

Comment: @rafaelmorais yes it's possible ... I have it in almost all of my projects ... post a question with the error you got and sure you'd find someone to help...

Comment: Will do, if you want to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291518/how-to-export-createstacknavigator-as-class-in-react-native