# How to export createStackNavigator as class in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, mobx-react

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551547/using-mobx-store-in-react-navigation-createstacknavigator) that using the the createStackNavigator as a Component class was possible, and I was trying to achieve that, but I always got an error.

**Instead of this:**

```js
export default createStackNavigator({
    Messages
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false
    }
})
```

**I tried this:**

```js
class MessagesStack extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const RouteConfigs = {
            Messages
        };

        const NavigatorConfigs = {
            defaultNavigationOptions: {
                gesturesEnabled: false
            }
        };

        const Stack = createStackNavigator(RouteConfigs, NavigatorConfigs);
        return <Stack />;
    }
}

export default MessagesStack;
```

But I always get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly. More info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html
```

So, I tried to correct it, by adding the navigation prop, like so:

```js
return <Stack navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
```

But then I got a new error

```
TypeError: TypeError: No "routes" found in navigation state. Did you try to pass the navigation prop of a React component to a Navigator child? See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html#navigator-navigation-prop
```

Is this possible? The main reason I want to do it, is to be able to @inject and use @observer for mobx stores. This way when I change de background color in the store, it will change on every stack that has the store injected and is observing.

**EDIT**

Where I'm calling MessagesStack from:

```js
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    DayStack: {
        screen: DayStack,
        navigationOptions: {...}
    }
    MessagesStack: {
        screen: MessagesStack,
        navigationOptions: {...}
    }
    ... OtherStacks here...
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'DayStack',
});
```

Comment: Can we see how you're using `MessagesStack`?

Comment: is your stack your main navigator ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox added that to the question

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli no, its part of a TabNavigator

Comment: @rafaelmorais

Docs: 
Note: In v2 and earlier, the containers in React Navigation are automatically provided by the create*Navigator functions. As of v3, you are required to use the container directly. In v3 we also renamed createNavigationContainer to createAppContainer.

You need to wrap your root navigator with `createAppContainer`

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli I'm not sure if I follow you. My root navigator is wrapped around the `createAppContainer()`, if I wrap `MessagesStack` also, it gives me a warning telling I should only render one navigator explicitly in my app.

Comment: @rafaelmorais One fast and tested way (from my end) is to downgrade to `react-navigation 2.18.3` .. and then remove this `createAppContainer` thing ... and every thing should work perfectly fine ... but I need to try something first before I can tell it works with react-navugation v3,

Answer (score 0):

according to my understanding from the error I think the issue is not with your createStackNavigator the actual problem is that now from version 3 of react-navigation you have to manually pass the createStackNavigator into the createAppContainer so that the created Container can be the main component for React native to render

```
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
// you can also import from @react-navigation/native

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(...);

// you have to pass the app navigator into app container like this
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

// Now AppContainer is the main component for React to render

export default AppContainer;
```